# Microsoft Windows Search Indexer - Preserving index while indexing (perhaps with a second index)

Tags: windows, search, indexing

I want to use the Microsoft Windows Search Indexer (the desktop Indexer, not the Azure Indexer) to index my files by content then query the index. That works, but I noticed that, when the indexer decides to re-index my files, the index is cleared and I get incomplete query results until the current indexing run has finished.

One solution I know of, is to stop and disable the indexer and restart it at a time of day when no-one wants to query it. That seems to have the side effect that queries aren't possible either when the Indexer is in stopped state.

Simply changing the index location won't work because the old index would be deleted, and queries could not access it any longer.

A more desirable solution, perhaps, would be for the indexer to have two indexes and switch from index A to index B when indexing has finished, and vice versa. I'd need a programmatic solution.

Does anyone know of such a possibility, or any other? Microsoft Windows Search Indexer has a lot of registry entries, but I found documentation relative scarce.

I have Windows 10, I use c++ for programming.

Many thanks in advance.